# SearchView on RecycleView bug

Tags: java, android-studio

So, im trying to add a searchView on my RecycleView ,but when im clicking the search icon,the app stops and i dont have any idea why.I have created a RecycleViewAdapet class with this code:

```
    public void updateList(ArrayList<String> searchList){
    mImageNames=new ArrayList<>();
    mImageNames.addAll(searchList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and inside my Emails acitivity there is this code about the searching :

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar,menu);
    MenuItem menuItem= menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView= (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    String userInput= newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String name: mNames){
        if(name.toLowerCase().contains(userInput)){
            newList.add(name);
        }
    }

   adapter.updateList(newList);

    return true;
}
```

i tried to debug and i have these [warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luHmR.png)
For the communication between RecyclerViewAdaper and Emails activity i created a  private RecyclerViewAdapter 
[adapter;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xavNu.png)
Any help

Comment: `adapter` is `null` when you call `updateList`. Did you assign the variable? Does the text change before you assign it?

Comment: i tryed now to do this http://prntscr.com/kx7pfj but now getting other errors http://prntscr.com/kx7pwr